# Set node value based on a parameter, a predicate and the current value

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

My current XML is something like this when simplified -

```
<wd:Settlement_Account_Data>
  <wd:Inactive>0</wd:Inactive>
  <wd:Bank_Account_Number>ABCD12345678</wd:Bank_Account_Number>
</wd:Settlement_Account_Data>
```

In my XSLT, I have a parameter as follows -

```
<xsl:param name="changeType"/>
```

This can be either 'A' or 'D', and is set dynamically by my underlying program.

What I want to do is set the value of "Inactive" as 1 if

1. The bank account number (sibling node) ends with 12345678.
2. Inactive is currently set to 0.
3. The parameter is set as 'D'

I tried the following 3 approaches, and none of them seem to work.

```
 <xsl:template match="wd:Settlement_Account_Data/wd:Inactive[ends-with(../wd:Bank_Account_Number, '12345678')]">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$changeType = 'D'"><wd:Inactive>1</wd:Inactive></xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><wd:Inactive><xsl:value-of select="."/></wd:Inactive></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>      
 </xsl:template>
```

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Settlement_Account_Data/wd:Inactive[ends-with(../wd:Bank_Account_Number, '12345678')]/text()">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$changeType = 'D'">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="."/></xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Settlement_Account_Data/wd:Inactive[ends-with(../wd:Bank_Account_Number, '12345678')][.='0']/text()">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$changeType = 'D'">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

In my output, I always seem to be failing with condition #3, i.e., the output has inactive set to 1 even if the supplier type is 'A'.

The following XSLT which avoids condition #2 seems to work though -

```
   <xsl:template match="wd:Settlement_Account_Data/wd:Inactive[ends-with(../wd:Bank_Account_Number, '12345678')]/text()">
         <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$changeType = 'D'">1</xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>0</xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
   </xsl:template>
```

Comment: How do the three attempts fail? Describe the exact error or output you get for each of them.

Comment: I can't reproduce that failure at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/pNvtBH1/1, the `Inactive` stays as 0. So perhaps show minimal but complete details of the XML, XSLT and the way you run the XSLT, to allow others to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this XSLT, basically running through the 3 conditions you have (I also removed the prefix 'wd'):

```
<xsl:template match="/Settlement_Account_Data/Inactive">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$changeType = 'D'">
                <Inactive>1</Inactive>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="ends-with(parent::Settlement_Account_Data/Bank_Account_Number,'12345678')">
                <Inactive>1</Inactive>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <Inactive>
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </Inactive>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>      
    </xsl:template>
```